# Buy X Get Y ,working But applying to whole cart

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

Below is my condition for cart rule

> If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE : If an item is FOUND  in the
>   cart with ALL  of these conditions true:  Price  greater than  10
>   Price  less than  150   SKU  is  test Dinner Plate

And action as follows:

> Apply - Buy X get Y free (discount amount is Y)  Discount Amount : 1 
>   Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To : 0  Discount Qty Step (Buy X) : 2

Now it works when I add 3 items of 'test Dinner Plate' to cart,! item price is added as discount.Price of  test Dinner Plate is 145 .

Now when I add 3 items of different sku 'Dinner Plate' , the rule is not getting applied but the moment I add one 'test Dinner Plate' to cart, the rule is getting applied to other product which is added to cart .

The rule is actually getting applied to the whole cart which has 3 items in cart.

Ideally this should be applied only to the sku which we have added to the rule but is not.
Is there any configuration missing while creating the rule .Please help

Comment: Please try _Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)_ and add 'test Dinner Plate' in condition

Comment: That option is for free shipping right

Comment: No, this option allows us to apply shopping cart rule to specific cart item based on condition(s).